# When is gamma and theta in the same direction?

Tags: options, option-pricing, greeks, theta

So, I am reading Natenberg and it says that during expiration(close to expiration), the deep in the money options will have Gamma and Theta in the same direction. This was a bit counter intuitive to me as to why that would be?

Comment: When you are long a deep in the money European option, in a world of positive interest rates, the option has little sensitivity to S and is essentially a discount instrument. It increases (positive theta) as the expiration date approaches just like a Treasury Bill appreciates, due to the Time Value of Money. This is an unusual case. OTOH the Gamma of  long option positiion is always positive.

Comment: See [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/73629/54838), last picture