Option Prices less than intrinsic value with Implied Volatility Solver
I have recently received a dataset with SPX options.
I tried solving for implied volatilities using a root solver. I noticed errors consistently popping up that is solvable via the answer given below:
AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility - root not bracketed issue in QuantLib/R (my solutions was to remove those options in my SPX options dataset).
Is it possible for options to exist with market prices that are less than the intrinsic value of the options?

Yes in theory, especially if the notional value of the contract is very large and so market participants may not have the capital to fulfil the contract. From what I’ve seen it generally happens during irregular market conditions and close to expiry. Although your question doesn’t make a lot of sense because cash-settled SPX options are European but you are linking to an American options question. Intrinsic < option value is less likely to occur with American options as they can be exercised immediately.

1 small tidbit: The only time I’ve seen it happen with my own eyes was on the Brazil market. Liquidity is lower, less money to move around and so (I’m assuming) option holders were happy to dump there options at a discount.

You can easily manufacture your own option price that is not less but so close above the intrinsic value that even the best root solvers will not find the implied vol.

Thank you all for your comments. @KurtG. is that true? Because once I removed all those SPX options with market price > intrinsic value, I no longer had any root solver errors. When you said so close above the intrinsic value, what exactly do you mean? Is there a particular tolerance?

Take your favourite programming language, implement the BS formula and an IV calculator using Newton-Raphson. Then play around with prices and IVs to find that particular tolerance for that particular code.

Is this for deep ITM Puts and calls? Also, do you really use the exact timestamps of the option quote when you compute your European market price? See https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/73629/54838 for a potentially helpful answer.

@AKdemy, thanks for the reference. I didn't, I just used the days to maturity as they are just the closing prices for the day itself. I'm guessing from your referenced answer, the reason why this is relevant is the part on interest considerations and dividends? Thus, Nd1 and Nd2 are not the "true" probabilities, which might cause the span of options considered plausible by the Black-Scholes to be incorrectly limited.

Pls add enough details to your question so that it can still be understood and answered properly even if the link in your question gets broken.

It's possibly for Black Scholes Merton (BSM) to have a price below intrinsic value as Enrico Schumann showed. The answer I linked in my comment above also shows this and goes into quite some detail. The screenshot below is from this answer (the shaded green area).

This is also what professional tools like Bloomberg's OVME show. Pricing a put, with made up numbers to make it easier to replicate, shows that the option price (25.87) is well below intrinsic (30).

OVMEs value can be quickly replicated with standard BSM closed form.
# packages 
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import pandas as pd
# Black Scholes formula
def BSM(S,K,r,d,t, sigma, cp_flag):
    d1 = ((np.log(S/K) + (r - d + 0.5 * sigma **2) * t) / (sigma * np.sqrt (t)))
    d2 = d1 - sigma * np.sqrt(t) 
    opt = cp_flag*S *np.exp(-d*t)* norm.cdf(cp_flag*d1) - cp_flag* K * np.exp(-r*t)  * norm.cdf(cp_flag*d2) 
    return opt

s, k, t, σ, d  , r , cp_flag= 240,  270,  90 /365, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1, -1
r = np.log(1+r* (90-2)/360)/t # account for ACT/360 with T+2 and make continuous (as needed in BS) 
print(r)
#price option 
c = BSM(s,k,r,d, t, σ, cp_flag)
pd.set_option('float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)
pd.DataFrame({"Option": ["Put"], "Price (Share)" : [c], "Instrinsic" : [k-s]})


As pointed out by @Ezy, in this answer, there are 2 circumstances that can lead to the value of an european option being lower than intrinsic value

deep ITM puts in presence of positive interest rates r>0
deep ITM calls in presence of positive dividend yield q>0

which also coincides with the 2 circumstances under which it makes sense for an american option to be exercised early.
Since SPX options are European, that is also possible for SPX options. Therefore, one should not exclude them just because they trade below intrinsic value. Also, the root solver should work in these cases. It may be that some quotes (not trades) are erroneous but this should really be the exception for SPX.
As I wrote in my comment, I suspect the actual problem is the specifications that you use. Do you use the exact time stamp of the option quote for all market data? For example, you cannot use end of day prices for the underlying, if the option quote was last updated early in the morning. You would need to use the SPX value at the exact time of the option quote.

Thank you @AKdemy for your detailed solution as always. I figured the inputs were the issue, thanks to the many great answers in this query (including yours).

Glad it helped. Getting rates and dividends right is actually difficult, even for simply European options. On top of that, getting the exact time stamps is also difficult, and frequently costly.

There are several ways this can happen to a practitioner.
To begin, let's denote by the letter $Z$ the Black-Scholes computed value of an option with zero plugged in as the volatility.
$$
Z = BS( S, \sigma=0, r, c, t)
$$
This is what I, at least, prefer to call the intrinsic value, for both European and American exercise.  (Other people often define it the same as exercise value).
Your problem is essentially that you are finding "market value" $M$ less than $Z$.
$$
M < Z ?
$$
This can happen in a few ways

In truth, there is no such thing as "market value" $M$, and it is common for bid prices to be strictly less than $Z$.  People commonly define the mid price to be "market value" but that's not tradeable, and can of course also be less than $Z$.
Even the offer price is less than $Z$, but not by enough for the difference to be arbitrageable.
Your underlying price was not measured contemporaneously with option market price, so your idea of $Z$ is different from what was being used by the market makers.
Your drift parameters (interest rate, carry cost) are sufficiently different from the market makers that your idea of $Z$ is different from theirs.  Usually carry cost is the problem here.
There are special costs associated with exercising the options (finding a short, or laying off a long position), and these are priced in differently by you and the market makers.  Again your $Z$ is different.

All this stuff tends to happen in the "wings" where gamma is small.  So the academics don't talk about it much.  But with practical data sets it comes up all the time.
Worth noting is that the opposite problem to yours comes up about as often: implausibly large implied volatilities in the wings.  This happens for basically the same reasons, e.g. a 1-tick offer price is equivalent to 1000% implied volatility.

Thank you @Brian B for the interesting take, this definitely goes very deep into the practical difficulties with option pricing in the industry.

Those SPX options traded at the CBOE are European-style options
( https://cdn.cboe.com/resources/spx/spx-fact-sheet.pdf ). American options should in theory never trade at less than intrinsic values, but European options can. (It happens when the price is at a level where the American option would have been exercised.)
Numerical example (in R) of a call with a strike at 80; underlier is at 100:
library("NMOF")
vanillaOptionAmerican(S = 100, X = 80,
                      type = "call",
                      v = 0.2^2, ## variance
                      r = 0.01,  ## interest rate
                      q = 0.05,  ## dividend yield
                      tau = 1/4  ## time to maturity
                      )$value
## [1] 20


vanillaOptionEuropean(S = 100, X = 80,
                      type = "call",
                      v = 0.2^2, ## variance
                      r = 0.01,  ## interest rate
                      q = 0.05,  ## dividend yield
                      tau = 1/4  ## time to maturity
                      )$value
## [1] 19.01


Thank you Enrico, can't believe I didn't manage to find this out. It seems like the reason is $q$ being sufficiently higher then $r$ in the case of the call option.
